# PHP emptied the session while redirecting from external site

Tags: php, api, session, twitter

I am trying to fetch the user token from twitter API. 
while redirecting from twitter API it stores the things in sessions. And I can fetch that credentials from session. 
It is working fine on localhost. but while doing so on live server I am getting an empty php session. it is showing an empty array

Comment: How many application servers do you have in production? If you have more than one server, then redirect from Twitter could come to the server where the user gets a new session without the values you set before transferring the user to Twitter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you checked to have `session_start()` in your scripts?

Usually, your local php deployment has php.ini setting `session.auto_start = 1` by default. on production server this may not be true, so it is crucial to explicitly define `session_start()` in your scripts if you want to be sure it will work anywhere.

Also check php.ini setting `session.use_cookies` if session id is sent to users browser by cookie, or it has to be sent manually via url query parameter like `?PHPSESSID=....`